# Open Excel workbook with form button

Tags: excel

I have created a form with 1 button, and I have also created an Excel workbook that is saved within my application.  My question is: what coding do I apply to the button to open the workbook?  For example, I burn the application to a disc and I give it to a coworker.  When my coworker clicks the button, it opens my workbook.  I know how to reference the workbook from my computer, just not from within the application itself.  The workbook was saved to the output directory via the "add existing item" then "copy always" setting.  Any help or a code walk through would be of great help.

Comment: Using VBA.net to create application

Comment: Is it WinForm application? and you want to open excel within your application?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Save the excel file as a resource and use this code.

In this case, I saved my file as `testing.xlsx" and embedded it as a resource named testing.

I could then access it using `My.Resources.testing` and write it back to the disk using `File.WriteAllBytes`

In this case, I wrote it to the application's working directory (wherever they saved it) as `My File.xls`.

I then opened it using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = New Uri(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).ToString() & "\My File.xlsx").LocalPath
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(New Uri(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).ToString() & "\My File.xlsx").LocalPath, My.Resources.testing)
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath)
End Sub
End Class
```

Embedding File:

[image: Embedding]

Results:

[image: Results]